# Ubuntu 20.04 freezing after several hours running

Tags: 20.04

I recently upgraded an HP EliteBook to Ubuntu 20.04 (from 18.04). Since then the system freezes almost every day after long hours running. It tends to happen late afternoon or in the evening after being booting early morning. Once the system freezes nothing is able to bring it back, calls to start a virtual tty terminal or to end the session with Ctrl-Alt-Del go unanswered. Only Alt+Print+REISUB budges the system into a boot sequence (and only if issued from the internal keyboard). There are reports of Ubuntu 20.04 freezing during boot and right after log on, but this is a different case.

I activated persistent storage for the systemd journal. In the last minutes before the last freeze the journal recorded the following:

```
juil. 20 17:05:01 luis-notebook CRON[28804]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
juil. 20 17:05:01 luis-notebook CRON[28805]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
juil. 20 17:05:01 luis-notebook CRON[28804]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
juil. 20 17:05:58 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3779]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4546560/4546560/0, res+swap = 4317184/4317184/0
juil. 20 17:05:58 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3793]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4493312/4493312/0, res+swap = 4239360/4239360/0
juil. 20 17:05:58 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3804]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4669440/4669440/0, res+swap = 4325376/4325376/0
juil. 20 17:06:12 luis-notebook nm-applet[2631]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
juil. 20 17:06:12 luis-notebook nm-applet[2631]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
juil. 20 17:06:12 luis-notebook nm-applet[2631]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
juil. 20 17:06:29 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3804]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4665344/4665344/0, res+swap = 4329472/4329472/0
juil. 20 17:06:29 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3793]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4485120/4485120/0, res+swap = 4235264/4235264/0
juil. 20 17:06:29 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3779]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4534272/4534272/0, res+swap = 4313088/4313088/0
juil. 20 17:06:42 luis-notebook nm-applet[2631]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
juil. 20 17:06:42 luis-notebook nm-applet[2631]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
juil. 20 17:06:42 luis-notebook nm-applet[2631]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
juil. 20 17:06:59 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3804]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4657152/4657152/0, res+swap = 4325376/4325376/0
juil. 20 17:06:59 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3793]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4476928/4476928/0, res+swap = 4231168/4231168/0
juil. 20 17:07:00 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3779]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4526080/4526080/0, res+swap = 4313088/4313088/0
juil. 20 17:07:29 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3793]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4476928/4476928/0, res+swap = 4239360/4239360/0
juil. 20 17:07:29 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3804]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4657152/4657152/0, res+swap = 4333568/4333568/0
juil. 20 17:07:31 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3779]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4526080/4526080/0, res+swap = 4313088/4313088/0
juil. 20 17:07:41 luis-notebook wpa_supplicant[1119]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-71 noise=9999 txrate=390000
juil. 20 17:07:42 luis-notebook nm-applet[2631]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
juil. 20 17:07:42 luis-notebook nm-applet[2631]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
juil. 20 17:07:42 luis-notebook nm-applet[2631]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
juil. 20 17:07:42 luis-notebook nm-applet[2631]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
juil. 20 17:07:42 luis-notebook nm-applet[2631]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
juil. 20 17:07:42 luis-notebook nm-applet[2631]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
juil. 20 17:08:00 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3804]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4644864/4644864/0, res+swap = 4329472/4329472/0
juil. 20 17:08:01 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3793]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4464640/4456448/-8192, res+swap = 4231168/4222976/-8192
juil. 20 17:08:01 luis-notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3779]: Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 4788224/4796416/8192, res+swap = 4317184/4317184/0
```

There are a number of "Memory pressure relief" messages, but I doubt this is a memory issue:

- The same sort of usage pattern with Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04 never lead to memory exhaustion (much less a system freeze).
- When the system freezes the hard disk remains inactive, the I/O led does not blink incessantly as when large swaths of RAM are swapped.
- This notebook has 8 GB of RAM and a 8 GB swap. Most of the time the swap area is empty.

Any hints on how to identify the cause?

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache memory?

Comment: Did you have any luck? Could you observe your RAM saturation during freezes? 8GB sounds like easily saturated.

Comment: These freezes have become less frequent, but still happen a couple of times per week. So far I have not detected a circumstance in which RAM gets saturated. If I load all the programmes I need at once it still remains under 5 GB. I mostly work with vim and ssh sessions to remote computers.